# MATLAB Official doc example colormap function not working for imshow?

Tags: matlab

I am learning FFT from this tutorial:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/fourier-transform.html#f21-16704

So I tried the example in the website in matlab. However, the frequency domain image is grayscale instead of colorful as specified by the colormap function. The only way I could make it colorful is by substitute the imshow function with the commented out version below.

Why does the colormap function not work in this case?

```
f = zeros(30,30);
f(5:24,13:17) = 1;
imshow(f,'InitialMagnification','fit')

figure;
F = fft2(f);
F2 = log(abs(F));
%imshow(F2,[-1 5],'InitialMagnification','fit','Colormap',jet(256));  % this works
imshow(F2,[-1 5],'InitialMagnification','fit');
colormap(jet(256)); colorbar                   % not work, gets greyscale image
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem - it's working fine in my machine. Could it be that you are executing different code than the code you posted? For example: `imshow(F2,[-1 5],'InitialMagnification','fit');colormap(jet(256)); colorbar;imshow(F2,[-1 5],'InitialMagnification','fit');`

Comment: Try the following: add `figure` command before every `imshow` (in the same   code line) as follows: `figure;imshow(f,'InitialMagnification','fit')`... `figure;imshow(F2,[-1 5],'InitialMagnification','fit');`...

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a problem with the axis you want your colormap. Replace the last line with the code below. `gca` refers to the current axis.

```
colormap(gca,jet(256)); colorbar
```

Comment: This does work, thx for that. However, according to documentation for colormap function: colormap(map) sets the colormap for the current figure to the colormap specified by map. The figure colormap affects all axes in the figure, unless you set an axes colormap separately.    So I'm a bit sonfused as it says "affects all axes".